# Django static file is not loading

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Here is my settings config where I store all

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/static')
print 'STATIC_ROOT == ', STATIC_ROOT
STATIC_URL = '/static/'



STATIC_ROOT ==  /Users/pk/Documents/jobs/ccdn/sid/static
```

In my html Im referring static folder as below but the files are not loading, I get a 404 error.
The js/jquery* is located under the static folder.

```
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.timepicker.min.js" %}"></script>
```

'django.contrib.staticfiles' is enabled in the installed_apps directive.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your static files of an app in a `static` named folder inside the app folder. Not in your `templates` folder but alongside. You also don't need `STATIC_ROOT` to be set - if you are on the development server; you only need that in production.

So create a `static` folder in your app folder, inside create `js`, `css`, `img` folders and put in them the proper files.

In your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %} # at the very top
<script src="{% static "js/jquery.timepicker.min.js" %}"></script>
```